# Potential Hardware Failure?

Tags: hardware, boot

This may not be the place to ask, so feel free to point me in the right direction and delete this if need be.

I've put together two Desktops before now, and am now attempting to put together my first server. These are the specs:

- AsRock Rack E3C246D4U Micro ATX Server Motherboard LGA 1151 Intel C246
- Intel Xeon E3-1275 V6 Kaby Lake 3.8 GHz LGA 1151 73W BX80677E31275V6 Server Processor Intel HD Graphics P630
- Black Diamond Memory 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM ECC Registered DDR4 2666 (PC4 21300) Server Memory Model BD16GX22666MQR26
- Samsung 970 EVO PLUS M.2 2280 500GB PCIe Gen 3.0 x4, NVMe 1.3 V-NAND 3-bit MLC Internal Solid State Drive MZ-V7S500B/AM

Then there's the case, and a 450W PSU. There's no gpu, as I intend to use Ubuntu Server with its CLI, which I assume the onboard video chipset could handle. I don't have a VGA cable, so I got a VGA-to-HDMI adapter and an HDMI cable.

My current problem is that, after putting everything together, the power turns on, the case fans light up and run, the cpu fan runs, the POST codes show on the motherboard, but my monitor can't find a signal.

I've tested the adapter, and confirmed that it works on a Desktop. I've tested HDMI cord, and confirmed they work on a Desktop. I've tested the monitors being used, and confirmed they work on a Desktop. This leads me to believe the problem is with the server's hardware.

I searched over the internet and found this link: [troubleshooting](https://forums.tomshardware.com/no-post-system-wont-boot-and-no-video-output-troubleshooting-checklist.1285536/), and tried the various steps. I've read through the motherboard manual (which for this motherboard is rather sparse, but straightforward), the cpu's 12v ATX cord is plugged in, the standoffs are under the motherboard only where there are screws securing it, there is no video card to fully seat nor power cords to connect to the absent video card, I've tried booting with a single stick of RAM in each slot, I've likewise tried booting with both sticks in the respective same-numbered slots (A1/B1, and A2/B2), the plastic guard over the CPU was removed, the CPU has notches to ensure it's installed correctly so I assume that's fine, I don't believe the pins are bent, no thermal paste got anywhere other than the cpu and its fan, the fan is plugged into the cpu fan port on the motherboard and definitely spins, no loose screws or things jammed against the motherboard, as I've taken it apart and put it back together multiple times, all static electricity was in theory discharged, step 17 idk about, the front panel plugs seem to be functioning properly, the power switch was indeed turned on (hence the powered on state), idk about step 20, haven't tried 21 yet (about to), I'm using the integrated video, everything seems tightly connected.

I'm not a novice, but I'm likewise not an expert, so I recognize there's a lot I've yet to learn. As far as I've researched, this hardware setup should work. I've tried having the Ubuntu Server OS boot drive with autorun plugged in on install, but not before I tried booting it solely with BIOS. In all cases, no signal is picked up on any monitor/TV I use. I wouldn't think I received a defective part, rather assuming I likely did something incorrectly. But for the life of me I can't figure it out.

If anyone has suggestions for the prospective server host that is myself, I'd be incredibly appreciative. Thank you!

EDIT: as per the comments' suggestions, I managed to try a VGA cord and the display finally came up. Guess you can't ignore the integrity of a non-adapted cord. Unfortunately a new problem has arisen: upon booting, it displays "PEI--Intel Reference Code Execution...", and tends to display 19, 00, then 20. Upon reaching 20, it gets stuck and never progresses. From what I've researched, it's possibly a RAM problem. I've tried having only one stick and in each slot, but it seems to have no effect regardless of wait time. Is it possible that the motherboard and RAM aren't compatible? As far as I could tell, the GB size and GHz were both in the range the motherboard noted it could handle.

Comment: I would test with a VGA cable, no monitor you have support VGA?

Comment: @yagmoth555 that's my next step, it's just that aquiring a VGA cable to test has been more demanding than I initially expected. I unfortunately made the mistake of ordering HDMI cables and an adapter as I didn't expect to use a video cable for the server full-time, so I'd have an extra HDMI cable to use afterwards. Regardless, I'm planning on testing that, but given I got the adapter to work with a similar build, it at least made me wonder if the lack of VGA cord wasn't the issue. If this hasn't been closed, I'll update on the status of the VGA cord test in a few weeks when I'm able to test it

Comment: VGA-HDMI adapters are [directional](https://superuser.com/q/1168228/144961). Make sure yours goes the correct direction. Also note that the VGA in this board goes to the BMC. The processor graphics are not used for display (though you can still do compute jobs on it). And try clearing the CMOS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was aware it was directional (and it seems to be the direct direction. I'll triple check), but this is my first time learning of a Baseboard Management Controller. Will a BMC not work for outputing to a display? I know processors or onboard video chipsets didn't have superb graphics capabilities, but was under the assumption that they could handle BIOS or CLI display. And assuming clearing the CMOS involves removing the lovely little disk battery, leaving it off for a solid few minutes, then putting it back in, I have now tried that. No luck as of yet.

Comment: Yes, you should indeed be getting a normal display out of this thing. It may be time to consider the possibility that you got a defective unit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's fully possible. Is there a way to rule out which part(s) are or are not causing the issue without having to order an entirely new set of parts?

Comment: I'd try a straight VGA cable to an ancient monitor that actually has a VGA input. After that I'd give up. You've covered pretty much everything else.

Comment: @MichaelHampton well, I managed to finally find my old VGA cable, and it just so happened to finally give me a display. It's now stuck on "PEI--Intel Reference Code Execution... 20", but from what I've found that probably means it's upset with the RAM. But at least it's actually displaying now. Thanks so much for your insight! I can't say I strictly understand why the adapter doesn't work on post-build boot, and why the VGA does, but it certainly seemed to do the trick.